# Rosbridge Server gives warning when I try to unadvertise or unsubscribe

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, rosbridge, rosbridge-suite, rosbridge-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there, I have a ROS Kinetic running Raspberry Pi 3 B (I have installed ros as a ROSberry installation, from the source as suggested), which runs Rosbridge Udp Server over it.
I am getting in contact with it via a Windows-10 Laptop which has a c++ program running to send JSON's to the Raspberry Pi. When I send advertisement or subscription requests system runs perfectly, I am able to publish/receive messages and create topics easily.
After I am done with the messaging, I want to unadvertise a topic (and unsubscribe) so that topic will be killed by ROS Master since there will be no subscribers or publishers left.
I am sending the following JSON's to unsubscribe and unadvertise:

- { "op": "unsubscribe",  "id": "C-R",  "topic": "top2" }  //for unsubscribing
- { "op": "unadvertise",  "id": "yp2",  "topic": "top2" }  //for unadvertising

then I get the following warning, which says (I believe) I am asking ROS to unadvertise or unsubscribe, but I specifically added ID parts to the JSON's just to make sure that ROS understand the request is coming me and I am asking ROS to make me unadvertise and unsubscribe. **Why am I having the warning and how can I fix this?**

> [WARN] [1564562740.474205]: Could not
> process inbound connection:
> [/rosbridge_udp] is not a publisher of
> [/top2]. Topics are [['/client_count',
> 'std_msgs/Int32'], ['/rosout',
> 'rosgraph_msgs/Log']]{'message_definition':
> 'string data\n', 'callerid':
> '/rosbridge_udp', 'tcp_nodelay': '0',
> 'md5sum':
> '992ce8a1687cec8c8bd883ec73ca41d1',
> 'topic': '/top2', 'type':
> 'std_msgs/String'} [WARN]
> [1564562741.499281]: Could not process
> inbound connection: [/rosbridge_udp]
> is not a publisher of [/top2]. Topics
> are [['/client_count',
> 'std_msgs/Int32'], ['/rosout',
> 'rosgraph_msgs/Log']]{'message_definition':
> 'string data\n', 'callerid':
> '/rosbridge_udp', 'tcp_nodelay': '0',
> 'md5sum':
> '992ce8a1687cec8c8bd883ec73ca41d1',
> 'topic': '/top2', 'type':
> 'std_msgs/String'} [WARN]
> [1564562743.519575]: Could not process
> inbound connection: [/rosbridge_udp]
> is not a publisher of [/top2]. Topics
> are [['/client_count',
> 'std_msgs/Int32'], ['/rosout',
> 'rosgraph_msgs/Log']]{'message_definition':
> 'string data\n', 'callerid':
> '/rosbridge_udp', 'tcp_nodelay': '0',
> 'md5sum':
> '992ce8a1687cec8c8bd883ec73ca41d1',
> 'topic': '/top2', 'type':
> 'std_msgs/String'}

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329714/rosbridge-server-gives-warning-when-i-try-to-unadvertise-or-unsubscribe/) by [mmp52](https://answers.ros.org/users/44060/mmp52/) on ROS Answers with karma: 80 on 2019-07-31

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See here: https://github.com/RobotWebTools/rosbridge_suite/issues/138

It seems like it is actually a bug in rospy (which rosbridge_suite is written in). Apparently unpublishing has been broken since 2013 (https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/111). So the issue does not arise when your client unpublishes/unsubscribes from the rosbridge server, but when the rosbridge_server itself unpublishes the ros topic.

A workaournd is to set the unregister_timeout argument to a huge value. Like 1 year, so rosbridge_server never unpublishes any topics. If you are publishing/subscribing and unpublishing/unsubscribing from a lot of different topics, this might become a problem over time.

This situation is quite dissapointing in my opinion.

---

Originally posted by [AndreasVH](https://answers.ros.org/users/45843/andreasvh/) with karma: 36 on 2019-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-19**:\

> This situation is quite dissapointing in my opinion.

This may not count as an excuse, but `rosbridge_suite`, as with just about everything in ROS, is an OSS project. It will depend on volunteers and maintainers to get things fixed.

Unless someone spends some effort to fix this in `rospy` and submits that fix, nothing will change.